# Sublime REPL terminal issue

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

Recently I started using sublime 3 text editor and the issue I encountered is the REPl terminal, I mean why is there syntax highlighting and autocompletion in a terminal during execution, it makes the terminal annoying, is there any fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **.sublime-settings** file, add `"auto_complete": false` in **SublimeRepl user settings**.

```
"repl_view_settings": {
        "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
        "auto_indent": true,
        "smart_indent": true,
        "spell_check": false,
        "indent_subsequent_lines": false,
        "detect_indentation": false,
        "auto_complete": false,
        "line_numbers": true,
        "gutter": true
    },
```

If this doesn't work, go to `SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu`, search for `autocomplete_server` and set it to `false`.

Comment: @Shradha yea, absolutely